# How to power board plus module with one battery pack

Tags: power, battery

I'm someone who's very new to robotics and the physical side of computers (software guy) so apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm purchasing an Arduino Nano 33 IoT that I'll be using in conjunction with an Adafruit FONA 3G Cellular Breakout (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2687). I'd like to be able to power the entire unit off of one battery pack but my problem is that both the Arduino and the Adafruit 3G unit have separate power inputs. Adafruit's website says that a Lipoly battery is required to run the unit. Is there any way to "pass through" or "split" power between the two units? This way I was thinking I could run everything off of one external battery pack. Optimally I don't have to use a Lipoly battery and I could use a large external battery pack connected to jumpers or a barrel jack.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-3g-cellular-gps-breakout/arduino-wiring

Comment: Note that the SIM4320 has a supply voltage range: 3.4~ 4.2V. So you can't just use any odd battery pack. It also, at times, uses a lot of power, so your battery has to be able to provide these short bursts of current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a breadboard and jumper cable. connect the VCC and GND of battery to a breadboard, do this for your Arduino and sim card module too. just remember they should be in a one row. GND with GND row, and VCC with VCC row
note: this way is okay just for debugging